# To delete the "del" action in Opportunity for the Quote related list

Tags: apex

Can anyone plz tell how the below can be done ?
I want to remove the "del" option from the below in the Opp object. removing possibility of entire Action column also would be OK. thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new VF page which suits your requirement and add that vf page as an inline page in the detail page

Comment: This is the only way to actually remove the action column as it is a standard feature of Salesforce Object Page Layouts.

Answer (score 0):

As you need edit option its not possible to update the setting in permission.

Best way is to create custom vf with edit (re-direct) as related list and put a trigger check to prevent from delete.